# How to retrive value from soap response jmeter

Tags: testing, xpath, soap, jmeter

I have this soap response and i need to get the value of the tag platformMessage i writed a xpath query but it doesnt work, checking the log file in jmeter in tells me this "Prefix must resolve to a namespace: ns2", heres the xpath query

```
/S:Envelope[@xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"]/S:Body/ns2:activateProductResponse[@xmlns:ns2="http://ws.business.api.fulfillmentengine.com/"]/return/platformMessage
```

heres the xml

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:activateProductResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.business.api.fulfillmentengine.millicom.com/">
         <return>
            <platformCode>1</platformCode>
            <platformMessage>Fail operation.El set-top box ya existe. Code Response:|22098: 22098: 1</platformMessage>
            <responseCode>13</responseCode>
            <responseMessage>Error executing action in platforn</responseMessage>
            <UUID>3cb49b29-513e-11e6-b5db-005056807f0c</UUID>
            <platformName>INTRAWAY</platformName>
         </return>
      </ns2:activateProductResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @xmlns:ns2 in the xpath is not valid because despite appearances a namespace is not the same as an attribute.

If you enable "use namespaces", then the following xpath should work:

```
/S:Envelope/S:Body/ns2:activateProductResponse/return/platformMessage
```

Or if you want a dirty (and slow) workaround, you can reference the node names like so:

```
/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*/[local-name()='activateProductResponse]/return/platformMessage
```

Answer (score 0):

you should read:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor
- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Assertion

pay particular attention to:

> As a work-round for namespace limitations of the Xalan XPath parser implementation on which JMeter is based, you can provide a Properties file which contains mappings for the namespace prefixes:
>   prefix1=Full Namespace 1
>   prefix2=Full Namespace 2
>   …
>   You reference this file in jmeter.properties file using the property:

- xpath.namespace.config

Look in jmeter.properties for this property and everything is explained clearly